# Django Rest Framework - Nested Serializer are lazy loaded?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am lovely using Django Rest Framework and have a lot of fun with it.
But there is one thing which disturbes me. I have a Model and in this Model are a lot of Foreignkeys. i.e:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    bought_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bought_orders')
    bought_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(OrderCategory, related_name='orders')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='orders')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, related_name='orders')
    purpose = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod, related_name='orders')
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    delivery_received_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_received_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='received_orders')
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

so I use the good ModelSerializer and by the way I use nested serializer i.e.:

```
class ReadOrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created = DateTimeField()
    updated = DateTimeField()
    bought_by = UserSerializer()
    category = OrderCategorySerializer()
    article = ArticleSerializer()
    supplier = SupplierSerializer()
    payment_method = PaymentMethodSerializer()
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    invoice_documents = InvoiceDocumentSerializer(many=True)
```

The problem is that the request takes about 1.7 seconds for only 50 order.
Okay, that was unexpected... I opened my Django debug tool and looked at the sql statements. Django Rest Framework or Django opens for every order a new connection and do a select statement.

Is there a possible way to walk around the problem? 
Turn off lazy loading or something I can change in my serializers?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem comes from the queryset, not the serializer. By default Django querysets do not follow relations and so the related fields are not populated.
In order to fix that you have to change your queryset to use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for `OneToOne` and `ForeignKey` fields and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for `ManyToMany` fields.

So lets say you are using DRF `ViewSets`, you can change your `get_queryset` method in the `OrderViewSet` to something like that:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Order.objects.select_related(
            'bought_by', 'category', 'article', 'supplier',
            'payment_method', 'delivery_received_by'
        ).prefetch_related(
            'tags', 'invoice_documents'
        )
```